# MySQL - CREATE TABLE trows error when similar CREATE TABLE doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, primary-key, create-table

I am making an ASP.NET website at the moment. In the Global.asax I have code for initializing some tables if they does not exist. The init blog_post and booked_dates part of the code executes properly and creates the table but the init image_info does not. They are quite similar and I cannot find what is wrong with the MySQL syntax.

Error message: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''description' TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id))' at line 1

```
        //init blog_post
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_post` (" +
            "`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT," +
            "`header` VARCHAR(255)," +
            "`bbcode` TEXT," +
            "`author` VARCHAR(255)," +
            "`time_posted` DATETIME, " +
            "PRIMARY KEY(id));", con))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }

        //init booked_dates
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `booked_dates` (" +
            "`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT," +
            "`author` VARCHAR(255)," +
            "`start_time` DATETIME," +
            "`end_time` DATETIME," +
            "`time_booked` DATETIME, " +
            "PRIMARY KEY(id));", con))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }

        //init image_info
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `image_info` (" +
            "`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT," +
            "`author` VARCHAR(255)," +
            "`file_name` TEXT," +
            "`title` TEXT," +
            "`album` TEXT, " +
            "'description' TEXT, " +
            "PRIMARY KEY(id));", con))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
```

Thanks for the help beforehand!

Comment: creating tables in a global.asax isn't good idea by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different set of quotes around description `'` it should be the other one

```
`description`
```

or since `description` is not a reserve word, you can omit the quotes if you want. You query should be:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `image_info` (" +
            "`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT," +
            "`author` VARCHAR(255)," +
            "`file_name` TEXT," +
            "`title` TEXT," +
            "`album` TEXT, " +
            "`description` TEXT, " +
            "PRIMARY KEY(id));", con))
```

Comment: Works! Thanks for the help! I will accept the answer in 10 min.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use `backticks` in your create table code.

```
"'description' TEXT, "
```

should be

```
"`description` TEXT, "
```

Answer (score 0):

`backticks` should have been used instead of `single quote`

```
"'description' TEXT, " +
```

should have been

```
"`description` TEXT, " +
```

Answer (score 0):

`"'description' TEXT, " +` has other quotes!

Answer (score 0):

No need to quote/backtick them anyway.